# in RDD how do you get apply function like MIN/MAX for an Iterable class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to find out the efficient way to apply function to an RDD:
Here is what I am trying to do :
I have defined the following class:

```
case class Type(Key: String, category: String, event: String, date: java.util.Date, value: Double)
case class Type2(Key: String, Mdate:  java.util.Date, label: Double)
```

then a loaded an RDD:

```
val TypeRDD: RDD[Type] = types.map(s=>s.split(",")).map(s=>Type(s(0), s(1), s(2),dateFormat.parse(s(3).asInstanceOf[String]), s(4).toDouble))
val Type2RDD: RDD[Type2] = types2.map(s=>s.split(",")).map(s=>Type2(s(0), dateFormat.parse(s(1).asInstanceOf[String]), s(2).toDouble))
```

Then I try to create two new RDD - one that has Type.Key = Type2.Key and another one that has Type.Key not in Type2

```
val grpType = TypeRDD.groupBy(_.Key1)
vl grpType2 = Type2RDD.groupBy(_.Key1)

//get data where they Key1 does not exists in Type2 and return the values in grpType1
val tempresult = grpType fullOuterJoin grpType2
val result = tempresult.filter(_._2._2.isEmpty).map(_._2._1)

//get data where Type.Key == Type2.Key
val result2 = grpType.join.grpType2.map(_._2)
```

UPDATED:

```
typeRDD = 
(19,EVENT1,TEST1,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT1,TEST1,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT2,TEST2,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(21,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(21,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(24,EVENT2,TEST2,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(24,EVENT2,TEST2,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(40,EVENT1,TEST1,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)

type2RDD = 
(24,Wed Dec 22 00:00:00 EST 3080,1.0)
(40,Wed Jan 22 00:00:00 EST 3080,1.0)
```

SO FOR THE RESULT 1 : I would like to get the following

```
(19,EVENT1,TEST1,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT1,TEST1,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT2,TEST2,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(19,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(21,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(21,EVENT3,TEST3,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)

FOR RESULT 2 : 
(24,EVENT2,TEST2,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(24,EVENT2,TEST2,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
(40,EVENT1,TEST1,Sun Aug 21 00:00:00 EDT 3396,1.0)
```

AND I THEN WANT TO COUNT THE NUMBER OF EVENTS PER KEY 
RESULT :

```
   19 EVENT1 2
   19 EVENT2 1
   19 EVENT3 2
   21 EVENT3 2
```

RESULT2:

```
  24 EVENT2 2
   40 EVENT1 1
```

THEN I WANT TO GET THE MIN/MAX/AVG FOR THE EVENTS

```
1. RESULT1 MIN EVENT COUNT = 1
   RESULT1 MAX EVENT COUNT = 5
   RESULT1 AVG EVENT COUNT = 10/4 = 2.5
```

Comment: please share the data and expected output

Comment: Are you looking for `countByKey`?

Comment: @hoyland.. countByKey..would that handle if there are Null values in the values in _._2

Comment: @hoyland.. countByKey blows up with the error : alhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String ... I debug it and the only thing that I would think would cause it is that there are null values in the value field for my events..

Comment: @EB I believe that's actually the `toDouble` blowing up when it's called on an empty string, totally unrelated to the `countByKey`.

Comment: @hoyland.. let me try deleting the nulls but i struggle in getting the grouping by the 2 keys i want to work